# Допустимо ли такое написание термина: "анжабеман"?

Tags: орфография, терминология

Словари предлагают только один вариант: "анжамбеман". Но поиск находит немало страниц с "анжабеман" (в том числе, в солидных изданиях — старых и новых, в литературных журналах, диссертартациях и т.п.). Является ли такой вариант допустимым? Может, это какая-то традиция, профессиональный жаргон?

Удивило ещё, насколько распространено явно ошибочное написание "амбажеман". Настолько, что Google не пытается исправить это слово. Более того при попытке ввести в строку поиска "амбажемен", например, предлагает заменить его на "амбажеман". (И это удалось найти даже в сборнике докладов конференции.)

Comment: Просто Н носовое, по-русски оно может быть ближе к отсутствию звука, чем к Н, поэтому я бы не сказал, что оно явно ошибочное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, орфографические словари рекомендуют написание *анжамбеман*, и, соответственно, оно является единственным нормативным, если не фиксируется вариантов.

Часто в профессиональной среде (филологии это касается особенно) ученые могут использовать в своих работах написание того или иного термина, которое, по их мнению, лучше отражает логику языка-источника (уверен, что французским владеет большое количество филологов), и, если оно распространено, то нельзя утверждать, что оно неправильно.

Вспомните термин *оксиморон*, который также и *оксюморон*.